# How to make a Lightning modal window pop-up with a quick action?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, quickaction, action

I am new to LWC development, but I do know my Apex code and VF pages. What I am looking for: clicking a quick action on a standard Lightning record page should open a modal Lightning window (which I am building).

Googling gives me results for LWC and for Aura, but I don't know if Aura is advisable to use.

To use an LWC in an action, you must have proper attributes in the .js-meta.xml file. I am fine with that. The .html file is also no problem. But then? The secret to a modal pop-up behavior is in the .js file, I think. What are the magic words?

I tried to implement force:lightningQuickAction as well as extend LightningElement, but that gives the error "implements clauses can only be used in a .ts file". So I think that that is not the way to go. And the documentation does not make it clear to me if force:lightningQuickAction is specific for Aura, or that it can be used in LWC as well.

Can anyone give me any pointers? Is it possible to do it 100% LWC or must I use some Aura as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: It's now Generally Available (GA) for LWC in [Summer '21](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_quick_actions.htm&type=5&release=232). For your use case (open a modal), you can utilize the `ScreenAction` actionType under the `Lightning__RecordAction` target now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
   <targets>
       <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
   </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
   <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
     <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
   </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

---

*Original Answer pre-Summer '21*:

It's not supported for Quick Actions as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/get_started_supported_experiences). There's an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TzwnQAC) to support this that I suggest voting on.

> **Unsupported Experiences and Tools**
>
> Lightning Web Components doesn’t currently support these Salesforce
> experiences and tools. **To use a Lightning web component with these
> experiences and tools, wrap the component in an Aura component**.
>
> - Salesforce Console APIs (Navigation Item API, Workspace API, Utility     Bar API)
> - URL Addressable Tabs
> - Conversation Toolkit API, Omni Toolkit API, **Quick Action API**
> - Standard Action Overrides, Custom Actions,    Global Actions, List    View Actions, Related List View Actions
> - Chatter Extensions

You'll have to either:

1. wrap the component in an Aura component

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction">
    <c:yourLwc></c:yourLwc>
<aura:component>
```

2. As Phil W mentions in the comment to this post, you can use the LWC "modal" as a screen in a Screen Flow. There's dedicated sections in the [LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-flow-support/documentation) [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_build_for_flow_screens) that concern Flow and there's examples out [there](https://unofficialsf.com/adding-lightning-web-components-to-flow-screens/).

Comment: An alternative is to actually implement the "modal" as a Screen in a Screen Flow. That obviously only works if what you are trying to do fits with what can be done with Flows and Screens.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me. In the idea I found a pointer to a Github project, https://github.com/1ktribble/Simple-Quick-Action-Lighting-Web-Component, that has a simple example of all the code that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is already supported since **Summer 21**

Check it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/05/learn-moar-with-summer-21-lwc-quick-actions.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.